# Connecting child BU to Salesforce Org, but don't have access to Synced Data extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I have an MC instance with multiple Business Units, I want to connect one of the child business units which serves a separate part of the business to their dedicated Salesforce org. There is no active Salesforce connection between the two systems currently.

While I've successfully connected the child BU and the SF org together, in the BU itself I do not have access to the Synchronised Data Sources despite being the only BU the account has access to (and also an administrator account).

My suspicion is that we cannot connect child BU's unless multi-org is enabled, can someone confirm? (as we do not have that feature enabled)

Comment: Have you shared the sync de?

Comment: I’m trying to select some objects from Contact Builder > Syncronised Sources first, there are no DE’s to share atm

Comment: do you have multi-org enabled?

Comment: No there is no multi-org enabled.. this is the first MC connected org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Marketing Cloud Connect in standard setup, you can only connect to the Parent BU which would be the "account level connection". There is no direct connection to a Child BU as it is not considered an account.

When changing the setup to Multi-Org, Child BUs for the sake of connecting Sales Cloud(s) act as their own account. With Multi-Org enabled, connections can then also be established between  SFSC Orgs and any BU (Child BUs included).
Which means that even in order to connect only one SF Org to a child BU directly, you would need to enable Marketing Cloud Multi-org.

Yet you still would not isolate the data.
e.g. All Subscribers would still be an account wide entity.
So while "circumventing" the parent BU in the flow of data, there still would be data surfacing there.

Hence it's kind of hard to construct a usecase where enabling multi org for ONE direct connection makes sense. Normally, you'd feed data into the parent through MC Connect and distribute over child BUs with SQL or sharing of the synchronized DEs. The only real downside to SQL being that the synch gets slower due to hourly automations executing the SQL instead of 15 minute data stream.

As a general note, DO NOT enable multi-org if you have not read up on it thoroughly.

You can only have it enabled by Support and it is officially an irreversible change.

Start here:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_multi_org_account_configuration.htm&type=5

Comment: I've specifically mentioned I am not connecting more than one org to multiple BU's. I am connecting ONE BU to a single Org. The BU just happens to be a child instead of the parent.

Comment: understood, in this case- all connections go to Parent BU. You cannot connect to a Child BU. Editing my answer to reflect this